# Context with TexMaker

Tags: context, texmaker

I'm using TexWorks to type my Context documents.
I wish to get folding (which is not, yet, implemented in TW).
I hoped to use TexMaker but I can't find the way to choose a Context build.
Did anyone succeed ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What OS and TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: Use `context` (ConTeXt MkIV, luatex engine) instead of `texexec` (ConTeXtMkII, pdftex engine)

Comment: But I don't know anything about texmaker. That is why I did not post an answer. The command should correspond to `context --batch %`

Answer (score 7):

This answer assumes you're on Mac OS X; the path to `context` may be different on Linux and will definitely be different on Windows, but the procedure for setting up ConTeXt in texmaker is similar, regardless of the OS you're using.

To set up ConTeXt in texmaker, do the following. Click on *User*, *User Commands*, *Edit User Commands*. You can define five custom commands there. Pick one that is unused (if any) and fill it as shown below.

[image]

Click *Ok*.

The new command will then be featured in the list of available commands.

[image]

You can test that everything is working by compiling this [ConTeXt Hello-World document](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Hello_world#Source).

[image]